# react-native StyleSheet borderRadus compatibility

Tags: react-native

I want to set up **borderRadus** style for containers.There are compatibility issues on ios, no rounded corners.Android above is ok.

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    dot: {
        width: 11,
        height: 11,
        borderRadius: 11,
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(170,170,170)',
        marginRight: 5,
      }
    });
```

```html
<Text style={styles.dot} />
```

Ios display in square.
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap a `View` outside the `Text` element. The `View` element does not have such compatibility issues